# PHP - Get date of next crontab's run

Tags: php, cron

I want to **get the next date to run the cron** from a given string like [Cron Format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) with `seconds` parameter (not fully equal as cron format).

**My code:**

```
$cron_format = explode(" ", "00 00 00 01 * *"); // <second> <minute> <hour> <day> <month> <week_day>
$date_diff   = explode(" ", "s i H d m w");     // php Date @link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
$format = [];

foreach( $date_diff as $key=>$value) {
    $format[$value] = $cron_format[$key] !== "*" ? date($value, strtotime($cron_format[$key])) : date($value);
}

$spf = sprintf(
"%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", 
date("Y"), $format["m"], $format["d"], $format["H"], $format["i"], $format["s"]
);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $spf);

// returns 2018-03-01 00:00:00, expected was 2018-04-01 00:00:00
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

[**Fiddle**](https://ideone.com/fI5n6L)

It reads `2018-03-01 00:00:00` as expected, but what I am looking for is a way to get next Crontab run date `(2018-04-01 00:00:00)`.

Setting a way to add a month does not solve the problem, since the *cron format* could be set hourly, as:

```
<second> <minute> <hour> <day> <month> <week_day>
   00       00      *      *      *         *
```

Comment: How about using this code? https://github.com/4andrisbriedis/crontab_to_next_time/blob/master/cronTranslator.php

Comment: Does the execution of cron jobs get recorded anywhere (log files, etc)?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix nop, but why?

Comment: @fiskolin, did you get a chance to check the code at link I posted?

Comment: cron expressions are way more sophisticated than you realize. You need to use a library. Don't be a hero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I played a little bit around and here is my result as a function. Basically I split the elements, check the values for Wildcards. If found it will ignore all other Wildcards and set the value for the element with the first Wildcard +1. Further I check the d and m for zero-values, and if found they are replaced by the value 1. In the end i check, if the date with the current year would be smaller than the current date. if yes, it will use the current year, if no it will use the next year.

```
 function calculate_next_cronjob($cronjob, $elementpositions){

  $wildcard = false;
  $elements = preg_split('/[^\d*]+/', $cronjob);

  foreach(preg_split('/[^a-z]+/i', $elementpositions) as $key => $element){

    $value[$element] = $elements[$key];

    switch($element){
     case 's':
      if($value[$element] == '*'){
       $value[$element] = date('s') + 1;
       $wildcard = true;
      }
     break;
     case 'i':
      if($value[$element] == '*'){
       $value[$element] = date('i') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
       $wildcard = true;
      }
     break;
     case 'H': 
      if($value[$element] == '*'){
       $value[$element] = date('H') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
       $wildcard = true;
      }
     break;
     case 'd': 
      if($value[$element] == '*'){
       $value[$element] = date('d') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
       $wildcard = true;
      }
      if(intval($value[$element]) == 0){
       $value[$element] = 1;          
      }
     break;
     case 'm': 
      if($value[$element] == '*'){
       $value[$element] = date('m') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
       $wildcard = true;
      }
      if(intval($value[$element]) == 0){
       $value[$element] = 1; 
      }
     break;
      default:
      unset($value[$element]);
    }

  }

  $cy = date('Y');
  $ny = $cy + 1;

  if(time() < mktime($value['H'], $value['i'], $value['s'], $value['m'], $value['d'], $cy)){
   $value['Y'] = $cy;
  }else{
   $value['Y'] = $ny; 
  }

  return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime($value['H'], $value['i'], $value['s'], $value['m'], $value['d'], $value['Y']));

 }
```

Testrun:

```
 $cronjobs   = array();
 $cronjobs[] = array('00 00 00 00 *  00', 's  i  H  d m N');
 $cronjobs[] = array('00 00 00 *  *  00', 's  i  H  d m N');
 $cronjobs[] = array('00 00 *  *  *  00', 's  i  H  d m N');
 $cronjobs[] = array('00 *  *  *  *  00', 's  i  H  d m N');
 $cronjobs[] = array('*  *  *  *  *  00', 's  i  H  d m N');

 echo '<table>';
 foreach($cronjobs as $data){
  echo '<tr><td>';
  echo $data[0];
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo $data[1];
  echo '</td><td>';
  echo calculate_next_cronjob($data[0], $data[1]);
  echo '</td></tr>';
 }
 echo '</table>';
```

Output:

```
00 00 00 00 * 00 s i H d m N 2018-05-01 00:00:00 
00 00 00 *  * 00 s i H d m N 2018-04-17 00:00:00 
00 00 *  *  * 00 s i H d m N 2018-04-16 09:00:00 
00 *  *  *  * 00 s i H d m N 2018-04-16 08:25:00 
*  *  *  *  * 00 s i H d m N 2018-04-16 08:24:59
```

Comment: That's soo close. When given `00 00 05 *  * *` (a possible hour at same day) it returns tomorrow's date.

Comment: i will try to fix it

Answer (score 13):

No need to write more code for that. Please use below library to do that

https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

Usage:

```
<?php
// Works with cron expression
$cron = new Cron\CronExpression::factory('15 2,6-12 */15 1 *');
$cron->getNextRunDate();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to reach same result without installing a public library.

Comment: Why @fiskolin ?

Comment: Just a heads up that mtdowling repo has been deprecated in favor of dragonmantank repo: https://github.com/dragonmantank/cron-expression